# How to map localhost to project directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

Currently I placed my project in `/www` directory of my Apache2 server, and I can access this project by `localhost/abc`
However I want localhost to map to this project, what should I do in order to make localhost to map to my project?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` or similar (it's specific to your OS/distro). I don't run Apache locally, so not sure if something like this could work.

```
<VirtualHost ip:port>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /www/your_project
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to httpd.conf you could put this into the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/$  /abc/
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html

Good Luck!